I would like to improve my Snowflake SQL query performance
I have a Snowflake query and I'm trying to improve the performance.
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
      AC
  FROM "DB1"."SCHEMA1"."TABLE1"
  WHERE
      AG   = 'PPPPPP'
      AND MG = 'CCC'
      AND MC IN ('11')
)
SELECT
    c.AC
    ,VC
    ,VV
FROM "DB2"."SCHEMA2"."TABLE2" v
INNER JOIN CTE c ON v.AC = c.AC
WHERE
   SC = 70
   AND VC IN ( 'V1', 'V2' , 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9', 'V10', 'V11', 'V12', 'V13', 'V14', 'V15', 'V16', 'V17', 'V18', 'V19', 'V20', 'V21', 'V22', 'V23', 'PP', 'HH' )
   AND GG = 'PPPPPP'

The first subquery is fast and returns 57,936 rows.
The "DB1"."SCHEMA1"."TABLE1" table has 22,852,551 rows (239.7 MB) and no cluster by.
The columns are:
Columns | Data Type
MI| NUMBER(38,0)
MG| VARCHAR(16777216)
MC| VARCHAR(16777216)
MN| VARCHAR(16777216)
AI| NUMBER(38,0)
AG| VARCHAR(16777216)
AC| VARCHAR(16777216)
AN| VARCHAR(16777216)
RR| VARCHAR(16777216)

The second subquery (and total query) is slow and returns 1,448,400 rows.
The "DB2"."SCHEMA2"."TABLE2" table has 23,449,693,351 rows (324.4 GB) and cluster by LINEAR(GG,SC).
Initially there was no cluster by but adding this cluster improved the performance.
The columns are:
Columns | Data Type
AC | VARCHAR(64)
GG | VARCHAR(64)
NN | VARCHAR(16777216)
SC | VARCHAR(2)
GI | NUMBER(10,0)
VC | VARCHAR(16777216)
WU | VARCHAR(255)
VV | FLOAT

How do I improve the performance of this query? I tried different query pruning technique such as not using a CTE, using temp tables, different JOIN ONs, etc.
The query went from 75s (no cluster) to 25s (with cluster) but I want it to be under 5s.
Please see Snowflake Query Execution Plan:

The query above is actually part of a bigger query but when analyzing the execution plan the issue is the TableScan on "DB2"."SCHEMA2"."TABLE2" where it's taking all the time.
The full query returns 23 rows.
Please see the full query below:
WITH

CTE AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    AC
  FROM "DB1"."SCHEMA1"."TABLE1"
  WHERE
    AG   = 'PPPPPP'
    AND MG = 'CCC'
    AND MC IN ('11')
),
 
CTE2 AS (
  SELECT
    c.AC
    ,VC
    ,VV
  FROM "DB2"."SCHEMA2"."TABLE2" v
  INNER JOIN CTE c ON v.AC = c.AC
  WHERE
    SC = 70
    AND VC IN ( 'V1', 'V2' , 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9', 'V10', 'V11', 'V12', 'V13', 'V14', 'V15', 'V16', 'V17', 'V18', 'V19', 'V20', 'V21', 'V22', 'V23', 'PP', 'HH' )
    AND GG = 'PPPPPP'
),
 
CTE3 AS (
    SELECT
      AC        
      ,VC
      ,CASE              
        WHEN "VC" IN ('V1', 'V2' , 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9', 'V10', 'V11', 'V12', 'V13', 'V14', 'V15', 'V16', 'V17') THEN 'PP'
        WHEN "VC" IN ('V18', 'V19', 'V20', 'V21', 'V22', 'V23') THEN 'HH'
      END AS BVC
      ,VV
    FROM CTE2
    WHERE VC IN ('V1', 'V2' , 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9', 'V10', 'V11', 'V12', 'V13', 'V14', 'V15', 'V16', 'V17', 'V18', 'V19', 'V20', 'V21', 'V22', 'V23')
),
 
CTE4 AS (
    SELECT 
      AC, 
      VC, 
      VV AS BV
    FROM CTE2
    WHERE VC IN ('PP','HH')
),
 
CTE5 AS (
    SELECT  
      v.AC
      ,v.VC
      ,v.VV
      ,v.BVC 
      ,b.BV
    FROM CTE3 v       
    INNER JOIN CTE4 b ON v.AC = b.AC AND v.BVC = b.VC 
),
 
CTE6 AS (
    SELECT
        "__PPPPPP" AS CG
        ,SUM("__C") AS CW
    FROM "DB3"."SCHEMA3"."TABLE3"
    WHERE "__ID" = TRUE
    GROUP BY CG    
),
 
CTE7 AS (
    SELECT 
        v.VC        
        ,SUM(v.VV * c.CW) AS TWV
        ,SUM(v.BV * c.CW) AS TWBV
        ,DIV0(TWV, TWBV) AS PC
    FROM CTE5 v
    INNER JOIN CTE6 c ON v.AC = c.CG
    GROUP BY v.VC
),
 
CTE8 AS (
    SELECT 
        v.VC        
        ,SUM(v.VV) AS TBV
        ,SUM(v.BV) AS TBBV
        ,DIV0(TBV, TBBV) AS BPC
    FROM CTE5 v
    GROUP BY v.VC
)
 
SELECT  
    b.VC
    ,w.PC
    ,b.TBV
    ,b.BPC
    ,((DIV0(w.PC, b.BPC)) * 100)::INT AS Index
FROM CTE8 b 
LEFT JOIN CTE7 w ON b.VC = w.VC;


i think you shared modified SQL which makes the CTE useless. Pls correct it, Now, you can try creating small table using the first CTE and add column VC to cluster by as well. hope this improves perf.

Can you send us the execution plan for the query, also did you try creating a Materialized view for TABLE1 and see if the time improves.

@KoushikRoy What do you mean by this and how do I correct it? Thank you.

SELECT DISTINCT   AC  FROM ...  WHERE  AC   = 'PPPPPP' returns 1( not 57,936 ) row -> AC='PPPPPP'. Pls, explain.

@HimanshuKandpal I have added the Snowflake Query Execution Plan. I did not try a Materialized View for TABLE1. How do I do this? Thank you.

@ValNik That was a mistake, I have fixed the query. Thank you.

Hi - what are you planning to do with the 1.4M records you’re query returns?

Since VC is varchar(2), one quick win is using the string literal '70' instead of the number literal 70. In a pathologic situation, the database type precedence rules could force the db to do a conversion on values stored in the table, instead of converting the literal to match the column. It's probably not happening here, but why tempt fate?

Another quick win: since they are same value, take the AC column from the 2nd table instead of the CTE. Won't make a lot of difference, but it could allow the DB to throw away CTE rows more quickly.

Third quick win: reverse the order of the clustered index on the 2nd table. Since SC only has two characters, it's likely to be far more selective than GG. However, this isn't guaranteed (just an inference), and if you use the index recommendation in my answer the code will look there anyway, instead.

@NickW The query is actually part of a bigger query (added above) but when analyzing the execution plan the issue is the TableScan on "DB2"."SCHEMA2"."TABLE2" where it's taking all the time. The full query returns 23 rows.

@JoelCoehoorn I have implemented your suggestions VC = '70' and take AC column from 2nd table instead of CTE. Your suggestions have improved the query significantly from 25s to now less than 10s. I will try implementing the clustering suggestions tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Thank you so much.

As you’re really filtering on AC, possibly getting rid of the join and doing WHERE AC IN (SELECT AC FROM CTE) might be faster

What size of warehouse are you using? Have you also tried using a larger warehouse to see the performance change? If there is no data skew issue, your query should run faster and not using extra credits.

This has to potentially compare fields from every row in the subquery with every row in the second table. 57,936 * 23,449,693,351 is 1,358,581,433,983,536. That's over a trillion potential comparisons to make. 5s may be ambitious.
Fortunately, there are things we can do. Correct indexing will be a big help (Snowflake calls this "clustering"). The most important index here will be for the second table. It's hard to be sure without knowing selectivity and actual-stored-size of the columns, but I suspect an index for (SC, GG, AC), in that order and in the same index (not separate indexes) will help.
I skipped VC from the main part of the index because there are a several values, so the selectivity is likely to be poor (it hurts the ability to walk the AC values in the index), and because the column is HUGE.
If this were SQL Server (what I use day-to-day), I would also recommend adding an INCLUDE section to the index for VC and VA. An INCLUDE section adds values to an index without trying to keep them sorted. Having them in the index allows the database to serve the query entirely from the index. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any indication Snowflake supports this, but I list it here in case I missed something. Additionally, as these are large columns you will want to test carefully whether the cost outweighs the benefit (also the VA column is missing from the table definition).
The DISINCT in the initial subquery also scrubs any index from the first table that might help. The database can be more efficient if it knows it has the rows in AC order. So you might get better performance with an index for the first table on (AC, AG, MG), where you also JOIN the two tables directly and then narrow to one row per AC via GROUP BY or similar after the JOIN... but it's hard for me to predict this.
If Snowflake supports it, some database systems also allow you to define partial indexes or views with indexes (SQL Server calls this 2nd option a materialized view). If you can do that for the subquery, then the database can be sure the rows will be in AC order, and the database can do the JOIN more efficiently.

Snowflake does not call indexing as clustering, Snowflake's clustering is not the same as indexing in traditional databases.
The key differences are:

Purpose:

Indexing in traditional databases is used to speed up data retrieval by creating additional data structures that allow for faster lookups.
Clustering in Snowflake is used to organize the data in a specific order to improve query performance, but it does not create additional data structures.





Implementation:

Indexes in traditional databases are explicitly created and maintained by the user or the database administrator.
Clustering in Snowflake is automatically managed by the system based on the specified clustering keys.


Effect on Queries:

Indexes in traditional databases are used by the query optimizer to determine the most efficient execution plan.
Clustering in Snowflake helps the query optimizer make better decisions about how to execute the query, but the clustering itself does not directly affect the execution plan.




In summary, Snowflake's clustering is a way to organize the data in a specific order to improve query performance, while indexing in traditional databases is a way to create additional data structures to speed up data retrieval. They serve different purposes and have different implementation details.
